# Javascript swiper not defined

Tags: javascript

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
},
});
```

I have gotten the codes from swiper api, navigation for my image slider. But when i input the script in my javascript file, the console log stated swiper is not defined. So how do i go about this?

[image]

Comment: How did you import the Swiper library?

Comment: Did you add the .js file before you `new Swiper()`?

Comment: Yes I did, in my index.js file

Comment: I import it from the github, and reference the codes from there

Comment: Can you show us how you imported Swiper, please?

Comment: Why? I mean, go for it. But the creators of the package likely have uploaded it to a package manager like npm. Or you could use a CDN, importing it through a URL reference with a script tag in your HTML. See the docs https://swiperjs.com/get-started/

Comment: Got it thanks Jacob Penney

Answer (score 2):

You have not included the js file of swiper, with this it should work fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
            navigation: {
              nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
              prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but I am using Google Optimize and I can't put a script tag in there. So I catch the script by this way:

```
var swiperScript = document.querySelector('.swiper-script');
var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.src = "https://unpkg.com/swiper@6.4.8/swiper-bundle.min.js";
swiperScript.appendChild(newScript);
```

I can see on "Sources" that it is being identified. But the console still informs me that Swipe is not defined.