# js function on vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

I am creating a slider using Swiper in my laravel project where the slider is in vue component. I linked the local js and css on my laravel master blade for swiper and written js code on windows.load for the swiper But it shows error in console.

```
app.js:3034 Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined
at window.onload (app.js:3034)

Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (swiper.min.js:1)
at e (vendors.min.js:2)
```

Here is my component code where I have my javascript as well:

```
    <div class="swiper-centered-slides swiper-container p-1">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide rounded swiper-shadow"> 
                  <div class="swiper-text pt-md-1 pt-sm-50">Getting Started</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="swiper-slide rounded swiper-shadow">            
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        </div>
     </div>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            window.onload=function(){
                var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
                direction: 'vertical',
            })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Am I doing any wrong in writing js in my component? whether or not I write the js it gives me not defined error. I am unable to understand why is the error showing up.
Help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you include swiper correctly? (JS/CSS). Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59083972/javascript-swiper-not-defined. Anyway its better to use CDN vs Local swiper. https://swiperjs.com/get-started/

Comment: yes i have linked it on my master blade